# Need to Generate List of 12 Months with Number of Days

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to generate a list of the last 12 months, with their number of days in each month, without using a lookup table. The requirement not to use tables was given by my jobgiver, also this query must work in any sql server.

I've found a solution for first column but it does not work:

```
WITH R(N) AS ( 
   SELECT 0 
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT N+1 
   FROM R 
   WHERE N < 12 
) 
SELECT 
    LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH,-N,GETDATE())),3) AS [month] 
FROM R
```

Does this solution must work, and tell me please what means R(N)? 
Also if you think it cannot be done on any RDBMS, please help me to do this in mysql?

Comment: What you have tried ?

Comment: Why sql, if you don't want any data from the DB?

Comment: Ive found a solution for first column but it does not work:
WITH R(N) AS
(
    SELECT 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT N+1 
    FROM R
    WHERE N < 12
)

SELECT LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH,-N,GETDATE())),3) AS [month]
FROM R

Comment: The requirement not to use tables was given by my jobgiver, also this query must work in any sql server.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Besides... if you aren't allowed to use any tables, why use the DB at all? You can get a list of months/days in most programming languages, without the need to use `sql`.

Comment: Peter Abolins, look a 4th comment of my question

Comment: @user3240998: Right... so "... _must work in any sql server_" actually means "... _must work in any RDBMS_"?

Comment: Peter Abolins, yes

Comment: @user3240998: Each RDBMS has its own syntax, so I am not sure that what you are asking is possible.

Comment: ok, do you know how to do this on mysql?

Comment: So, your employer has asked you to write a query that obtains the days of the months, for the last 12 months, which will work on any RDBMS? Seriously? Firstly, we're not here to do you're work for you, but also (and no offence to them) it sounds like your employer has no idea what they're talking about; or it's a trick question. What is their reasoning for not using a lookup table as well? Why must it work on every RDBMS (which it isn't, as although some are similar, others aren't).

Comment: Found a solution but it does not work is not very clear.  VTC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work in `sql-server` (as per the current tag). If you want it in `oracle` or `mysql` or `postgres` or `...`, the syntax will be different.

```
WITH R(N) AS ( 
   SELECT 0 
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT N+1 
   FROM R 
   WHERE N < 11 
) 
SELECT 
    LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH,-N,GETDATE())),3) AS [month],
    DAY(EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,-N,GETDATE()))) AS [days] 
FROM R
```

**EDIT**

To be honest, figuring this out for **any** RDBMS is practically a walk in the park, but I don't want to spoil the fun for you. I have however added a version which works in `mysql`.

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL R.mth MONTH)) AS Month,
       DAY(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL R.mth MONTH))) AS Days
FROM 
    (SELECT 1 AS mth 
     UNION SELECT 2 
     UNION SELECT 3 
     UNION SELECT 4 
     UNION SELECT 5 
     UNION SELECT 6 
     UNION SELECT 7 
     UNION SELECT 8 
     UNION SELECT 9 
     UNION SELECT 10 
     UNION SELECT 11 
     UNION SELECT 12) AS R
```

Comment: Thanks very much to Peter Abolins, now I've figured how to do what I need:

Comment: SELECT MONTHNAME(DATE_ADD('2017/12/01', INTERVAL R.mth MONTH)) AS Month,
       DAY(LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD('2017/12/01', INTERVAL R.mth MONTH))) AS Days
FROM 
    (SELECT 1 AS mth 
     UNION SELECT 2 
     UNION SELECT 3 
     UNION SELECT 4 
     UNION SELECT 5 
     UNION SELECT 6 
     UNION SELECT 7 
     UNION SELECT 8 
     UNION SELECT 9 
     UNION SELECT 10 
     UNION SELECT 11 
     UNION SELECT 12) AS R